# Windows 10 - PlayReady - DRM - ProtectionManager not firing in UWP application

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, drm, windows-media-player, playready

I recently implemented a working UWP application with PlayReady DRM based on the example code found here https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming/cs/Helpers/PlayReadyHelper.cs with an aim to playback protected content.

This application was built in Windows 10 running within a VirtualBox VM and worked as expected (i.e. The protection manager made a PlayReadyLicenseAcquisitionServiceRequest, playback successfully decrypted the content).

However, on moving the application code to a physical windows 10 machine (multiple versions tried). For some reason, the above no longer works, specifically the event never even fires and therefore the license isn't requested. This event https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming/cs/Helpers/PlayReadyHelper.cs#L99 (The individualization request does fire on first time use as expected)

I am binding the event in the same way in both the VM and the Physical machine i.e. `protectionManager.ServiceRequested += new ServiceRequestedEventHandler(ProtectionManager_ServiceRequested);`

So, my question is, what would cause protectionManager.ServiceRequested to not fire. I was hypothesizing that maybe hardware DRM was a cause here, and I tried forcing software which didn't appear to change anything.

Updated: I managed to find this error Media Failed::MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0x80041108 but again, still makes no sense why the src would work in the VM and not on the physical machine.

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks,
J

Comment: I tested with officical code sample, I think the event only occurs when the stream is protection

Comment: Yes, we already know this. The stream is protected, but the event is only firing when in the virtual machine and not on the physical machine. The problem is that it is not firing, even when the content is protected.

Comment: A part of DRM playback is initialization of video hardware for playback of protected content. It might be a problem in video driver that makes playback stumble and then forward the error upwards interrupting the playback. Chances are that you can fix it with video adapter driver upgrade or downgrade.